# Compactness of an operator using sequences

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to learn how to prove the compactness of an operator using the following definition: An operator $L$ is compact if for a bounded sequence $\{ x_n\}$, there exists a convergent subsequence $\{ x_{n_k}\}_k$.

**Example.** Define the linear operator $T : L_2[0, 1] \rightarrow L_2[0, 1]$ by
$$Tf(x) = \int_0^x \int_y^1 f(z)\,dz\,dy.$$

I want to prove it's compact. Take a bounded sequence $\{f_n\}\subset L_2[0,1]$. The domain of each $f_n$ is compact but $f_n$'s are not continuous themselves. So, I cannot say anything about $Lf_n$'s. Can someone help me out here please?

Can I just argue that because $T$ is a bounded linear operator and $dim(R(T))<\infty$, then $L$ is compact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $L^2[0, 1]$ has a complete orthonormal basis, say $\mathcal{B}=\{e_k\}$. In fact, the basis for $L^2[0, 1]$ is given by the set $\{e^{2\pi ni x}\}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence $T$ formally has the matrix representation 
\begin{align}
[T]_\mathcal{B} = \sum_{m, n \in \mathbb{Z}} \langle e_m, Te_n\rangle e_m \otimes \bar e_n. 
\end{align}

Note that 
\begin{align}
Te_n = \int^x_0\int^1_y e^{2\pi i n z}\ dzdy = \int^x_0 \frac{1-e^{2\pi in y}}{2\pi in}\ dy = \frac{x}{2\pi in}-\frac{e^{2\pi inx}-1}{(2\pi in)^2}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\langle e_m, Te_n\rangle = \int^1_0 \frac{xe^{-2\pi i m x}}{2\pi in}-\frac{e^{2\pi i(n-m)x}-e^{-2\pi i mx}}{(2\pi in)^2} =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2\pi^2n^2}& m=n,\\
\frac{1}{4\pi^2mn} & m\ne n
\end{cases}.
\end{align}
This shows that the matrix representation is well-defined since the coefficients are absolutely summable.

Next, define the sequence of finite rank operators
\begin{align}
T_N = \sum_{|n|, |m|\leq N}\langle e_m, Te_n\rangle e_m \otimes \bar e_n
\end{align}
and observe that
\begin{align}
\|T_N - T\|_\text{op} \leq \left(\sum^\infty_{m, n = N+1}|\langle e_m, Te_n\rangle |^2 \right)^{1/2}\rightarrow 0
\end{align}
when $N\rightarrow \infty$, i.e. $T$ is the limit of a sequence of finite rank operator. So $T$ is compact. This is along the line of your second question.

Comment: Based on what you said $dim(R(T))=\infty$. So, I can't use my second argument,  right?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. The range of $T$ is definitely not finite dimensional on $L^2[0, 1]$.

Comment: How did you get 

\begin{align} \int^1_0 \frac{xe^{-2\pi i m x}}{2\pi in}-\frac{e^{2\pi i(n-m)x}-e^{-2\pi i mx}}{(2\pi in)^2} =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2\pi^2n^2}& m=n,\\
\frac{1}{4\pi^2mn} & m\ne n
\end{cases}.
\end{align}